# How do you automatically download external (C++) libraries when using native Node addons?

Tags: node.js, node.js-addon

I'd like to include libpng in my native Node addon. How can I include it, so that when my library is installed, it will automatically download a specified version of libpng? Is it possible to use npm's package.json for this? If this is not possible, what is the accepted way of including an external library's source code in your repository?

Comment: "Native" Node application?

Comment: @Wainage a native add-on for Node, particularly one using Nan

Answer (score 2):

I recommend that you create a `gyp` file to build the dependency library and add a script to your `package.json` to download it for you.

I often use my own native addon modules to demonstrate the answers I give to these questions.  My own native addon module, [node-dvbtee](http://github.com/mkrufky/node-dvbtee), demonstrates this.

You will notice the following inside `package.json`:

```
  "scripts": {
    "preinstall": "npm install mkdirp && scripts/prepare-build.sh && node scripts/configure-build.js",
    "install": "node-gyp rebuild -j 8",
    "test": "mocha"
  },
```

What matters here is the `preinstall` section of the `scripts` section.  It calls `scripts/prepare-build.sh`, which contains the following:

```
#!/bin/sh

cd "$(dirname "$0")"/..

if [ -e libdvbtee ]; then
    echo libdvbtee sources present
else
    git clone git://github.com/mkrufky/libdvbtee.git
fi

cd libdvbtee

if [ -e libdvbpsi/bootstrap ]; then
    echo libdvbpsi sources present
else
    rm -rf libdvbpsi
    git clone git://github.com/mkrufky/libdvbpsi.git
    cd libdvbpsi
    touch .dont_del
    cd ..
fi
```

As you can see, the above script checks to see if the `libdvbtee` directory is present.  If not, it will clone it from github.  After that, it checks to see if the full `libdvbpsi` sources are present.  If not, it will clone them from github.

Now, for the `gyp` files:

My project has the `gyp` files stored in the `deps` directory.

`libdvbpsi.gyp` looks like this:

```
{
  'target_defaults': {
    'default_configuration': 'Debug',
    'configurations': {
      'Debug': {
        'defines': [ 'DEBUG', '_DEBUG' ],
        'msvs_settings': {
          'VCCLCompilerTool': {
            'RuntimeLibrary': 1, # static debug
          },
        },
      },
      'Release': {
        'defines': [ 'NDEBUG' ],
        'msvs_settings': {
          'VCCLCompilerTool': {
            'RuntimeLibrary': 0, # static release
          },
        },
      }
    },
    'msvs_settings': {
      'VCLinkerTool': {
        'GenerateDebugInformation': 'true',
      },
    },
    'include_dirs': [
      '../libdvbtee/libdvbpsi/src',
      '../libdvbtee/libdvbpsi/src/tables',
      '../libdvbtee/libdvbpsi/src/descriptors',
      '../libdvbtee/libdvbpsi'
    ],
    'defines': [
      'PIC',
      'HAVE_CONFIG_H'
    ],
  },

  'targets': [
    # libdvbpsi
    {
      'target_name': 'dvbpsi',
      'product_prefix': 'lib',
      'type': 'static_library',
      'sources': [
        '../libdvbtee/libdvbpsi/src/dvbpsi.c',
        '../libdvbtee/libdvbpsi/src/psi.c',
        '../libdvbtee/libdvbpsi/src/demux.c',
        '../libdvbtee/libdvbpsi/src/descriptor.c',
        '../libdvbtee/libdvbpsi/src/tables/pat.c',
        '../libdvbtee/libdvbpsi/src/tables/pmt.c',
        '../libdvbtee/libdvbpsi/src/tables/sdt.c',
        '../libdvbtee/libdvbpsi/src/tables/eit.c',
#       '../libdvbtee/libdvbpsi/src/tables/cat.c',
        '../libdvbtee/libdvbpsi/src/tables/nit.c',
        '../libdvbtee/libdvbpsi/src/tables/tot.c',
#       '../libdvbtee/libdvbpsi/src/tables/sis.c',
#       '../libdvbtee/libdvbpsi/src/tables/bat.c',
#       '../libdvbtee/libdvbpsi/src/tables/rst.c',
        '../libdvbtee/libdvbpsi/src/tables/atsc_vct.c',
        '../libdvbtee/libdvbpsi/src/tables/atsc_stt.c',
        '../libdvbtee/libdvbpsi/src/tables/atsc_eit.c',
        '../libdvbtee/libdvbpsi/src/tables/atsc_ett.c',
        '../libdvbtee/libdvbpsi/src/tables/atsc_mgt.c',
#       '../libdvbtee/libdvbpsi/src/descriptors/dr_02.c',
#       '../libdvbtee/libdvbpsi/src/descriptors/dr_03.c',
#       '../libdvbtee/libdvbpsi/src/descriptors/dr_04.c',
#       '../libdvbtee/libdvbpsi/src/descriptors/dr_05.c',
#       '../libdvbtee/libdvbpsi/src/descriptors/dr_06.c',
#       '../libdvbtee/libdvbpsi/src/descriptors/dr_07.c',
#       '../libdvbtee/libdvbpsi/src/descriptors/dr_08.c',
#       '../libdvbtee/libdvbpsi/src/descriptors/dr_09.c',
        '../libdvbtee/libdvbpsi/src/descriptors/dr_0a.c',
#       '../libdvbtee/libdvbpsi/src/descriptors/dr_0b.c',
#       '../libdvbtee/libdvbpsi/src/descriptors/dr_0c.c',
#       '../libdvbtee/libdvbpsi/src/descriptors/dr_0d.c',
#       '../libdvbtee/libdvbpsi/src/descriptors/dr_0e.c',
#       '../libdvbtee/libdvbpsi/src/descriptors/dr_0f.c',
#       '../libdvbtee/libdvbpsi/src/descriptors/dr_10.c',
#       '../libdvbtee/libdvbpsi/src/descriptors/dr_11.c',
#       '../libdvbtee/libdvbpsi/src/descriptors/dr_12.c',
#       '../libdvbtee/libdvbpsi/src/descriptors/dr_13.c',
#       '../libdvbtee/libdvbpsi/src/descriptors/dr_14.c',
#       '../libdvbtee/libdvbpsi/src/descriptors/dr_1b.c',
#       '../libdvbtee/libdvbpsi/src/descriptors/dr_1c.c',
#       '../libdvbtee/libdvbpsi/src/descriptors/dr_24.c',
#       '../libdvbtee/libdvbpsi/src/descriptors/dr_40.c',
#       '../libdvbtee/libdvbpsi/src/descriptors/dr_41.c',
#       '../libdvbtee/libdvbpsi/src/descriptors/dr_42.c',
#       '../libdvbtee/libdvbpsi/src/descriptors/dr_43.c',
#       '../libdvbtee/libdvbpsi/src/descriptors/dr_44.c',
#       '../libdvbtee/libdvbpsi/src/descriptors/dr_45.c',
#       '../libdvbtee/libdvbpsi/src/descriptors/dr_47.c',
        '../libdvbtee/libdvbpsi/src/descriptors/dr_48.c',
#       '../libdvbtee/libdvbpsi/src/descriptors/dr_49.c',
#       '../libdvbtee/libdvbpsi/src/descriptors/dr_4a.c',
#       '../libdvbtee/libdvbpsi/src/descriptors/dr_4b.c',
#       '../libdvbtee/libdvbpsi/src/descriptors/dr_4c.c',
        '../libdvbtee/libdvbpsi/src/descriptors/dr_4d.c',
#       '../libdvbtee/libdvbpsi/src/descriptors/dr_4e.c',
#       '../libdvbtee/libdvbpsi/src/descriptors/dr_4f.c',
#       '../libdvbtee/libdvbpsi/src/descriptors/dr_50.c',
#       '../libdvbtee/libdvbpsi/src/descriptors/dr_52.c',
#       '../libdvbtee/libdvbpsi/src/descriptors/dr_53.c',
#       '../libdvbtee/libdvbpsi/src/descriptors/dr_54.c',
#       '../libdvbtee/libdvbpsi/src/descriptors/dr_55.c',
#       '../libdvbtee/libdvbpsi/src/descriptors/dr_56.c',
#       '../libdvbtee/libdvbpsi/src/descriptors/dr_58.c',
#       '../libdvbtee/libdvbpsi/src/descriptors/dr_59.c',
#       '../libdvbtee/libdvbpsi/src/descriptors/dr_5a.c',
        '../libdvbtee/libdvbpsi/src/descriptors/dr_62.c',
#       '../libdvbtee/libdvbpsi/src/descriptors/dr_66.c',
#       '../libdvbtee/libdvbpsi/src/descriptors/dr_69.c',
#       '../libdvbtee/libdvbpsi/src/descriptors/dr_73.c',
#       '../libdvbtee/libdvbpsi/src/descriptors/dr_76.c',
#       '../libdvbtee/libdvbpsi/src/descriptors/dr_7c.c',
        '../libdvbtee/libdvbpsi/src/descriptors/dr_81.c',
        '../libdvbtee/libdvbpsi/src/descriptors/dr_83.c',
        '../libdvbtee/libdvbpsi/src/descriptors/dr_86.c',
#       '../libdvbtee/libdvbpsi/src/descriptors/dr_8a.c',
        '../libdvbtee/libdvbpsi/src/descriptors/dr_a0.c',
        '../libdvbtee/libdvbpsi/src/descriptors/dr_a1.c',
      ],
      'conditions': [
        ['OS=="mac"',
          {
            'xcode_settings': {
              'WARNING_CFLAGS': [
                '-Wno-deprecated-declarations'
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      ],
      'cflags!': ['-Wdeprecated-declarations','-Wimplicit-function-declaration'],
      'cflags+': ['-Wno-deprecated-declarations','-Wno-implicit-function-declaration','-std=c99'],
    },
  ]
}
```

Of course, there are a lot of specifics in this `gyp` file that are specific to `libdvbpsi` and my use case.  As such, you will notice that quite a few of the source files in the library are not actually needed for the version of it that we're going to build for my node.js addon module.  The source files that we are not going to build are commented out by preceding that line with a hash `#` character.

We link this library to the node module we're currently building by including it in the dependency section of the node.js addon modules `bindings.gyp`.  Here is the one used in my addon module:

```
{
  "targets": [
    {
      "target_name": "dvbtee",
      "sources": [
        "src/node-dvbtee.cc",
        "src/dvbtee-parser.cc"
      ],
      "dependencies": [
        'deps/libdvbtee.gyp:dvbtee_parser'
      ],
      "include_dirs": [
        "libdvbtee/usr/include",
        "libdvbtee/libdvbtee",
        "libdvbtee/libdvbtee/decode",
        "libdvbtee/libdvbtee/decode/table",
        "libdvbtee/libdvbtee/decode/descriptor",
        "<!(node -e \"require('nan')\")"
      ],
      'cflags': [ '-DDEBUG_CONSOLE=1' ],
      'cflags_cc': [ '-DDEBUG_CONSOLE=1', '-Wno-deprecated-declarations' ],
      'cflags!': [ '-fno-exceptions' ],
      'cflags_cc!': [ '-fno-exceptions', '-Wdeprecated-declarations' ],
      'conditions': [
        ['OS=="mac"', {
          'xcode_settings': {
            'WARNING_CFLAGS': [
              '-Wno-deprecated-declarations'
            ],
            'GCC_ENABLE_CPP_EXCEPTIONS': 'YES'
          }
        }]
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

As you can see, `deps/libdvbtee.gyp:dvbtee_parser` is listed in the `dependencies` section, above.  `deps/libdvbtee.gyp:dvbtee_parser` itself contains its own `dependencies` section:

```
  "dependencies": [
    'libdvbpsi.gyp:dvbpsi'
  ],
```

So, when `npm install` is executed, `npm` will run the `preinstall` script to fetch the sources, then it will build the custom `libdvbpsi` library based on `libdvbpsi.gyp`, then build the custom `libdvbtee` based on `libdvbtee.gyp` which depends on that custom `libdvbpsi` library, and finally it will build and link the node.js addon module that depends on the `libdvbtee` library build.

In my specific case, the libraries need to be configured before we attempt to build them.  This step is required to write the `config.h` header file that these libraries depend on.  I handle that step within the `scripts/configure-build.js` script which is run after downloading the sources.  In most cases, you will want to simply run `./configure` for each library, but that depends on the libraries that you're including.

This is a cross-platform solution, provided that the libraries you're building are themselves cross-platform.

Comment: It turns out that your script for cloning the repo is not cross-platform, I guess it will not work on Windows. We can use Node.js or Python scripts for that

Answer (score 0):

You can add it in scrips section in package.json. But you have to be careful about which all devices your application will be executed. Such as ARM, Intel 32 bit or Intel 64 bit, or so. You have options, I am just adding some hints here and you can put your code accordingly. Here script will get executed during `npm install` command.
 1. In script, you have to check the machine type and do download library accordingly.

```
//package.json
{
      "scripts": {
          "preinstall": ""
          ,"install": ""
          ,"test" : ""
       }
}
```

1. In script, you have to check the machine type and do download library accordingly, something like using `wget abc.so` in install section of script. You have to do some scripting to take right lib for machine and put in right place.
2. In other way if you want, you can add build script, which will do download the source code and build in the system on the fly.
   `git clone git://xyz/abc.git 
   cd abc
   ./configure 
   make 
   make install`.
3. You can also look for babel cli for source compilation. https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/cli/

And all these within scripts section, within preinstall or install or test.
In your case, you would prefer to go for 1st way.